# No puedo retornar valor de una función de evento onchange para Google Heatmaps

Tags: javascript, json, eventos

Tengo un Json con datos de geolocalización, nombre, zona, región, fecha, etc. Quisiera poder filtrarlo utilizando múltiples desplegables utilizando el evento onchange para poder utilizarlo en la plantilla de Google Heatmap. Sí pude filtrarlos pero no puedo retornar su valor para poder utilizarlo en otra función (los datos no son los originales). El siguiente script realiza el filtro de la cadena JSON.

```
//tengo un JSON obtenida mediante un url
var objetoJS = JSON.parse(Get(urlJsonBD));
//creo la funcion "disparador" que activa el evento
function disparador(){
    //capturo los select usando sus id y value
    var A = document.getElementById("A").value;
    var B = document.getElementById("B").value;
    var C = document.getElementById("C").value;
    
    //* aquí filtro el JSON por 3 condiciones utilizando sus value y el método filter*
    var filtrarA = objetoJS.filter(/*filtro 1*/)
    var filtrarB = filtrarA.filter(/*filtro 2*/)
    var filtrarC = filtrarB.filter(/*filtro 3*/)
    
    //extraigo la Geolocalizacion de cada elemento de la JSON y la concateno para darle forma
    var Arr[]
    for(var i = 0; i<filtrarC.length;i++){
        Arr[i] = " new google.maps.LatLng(" + filtrarC[i].Geolocalizacion + ")";
    }
    //convierto a cadena de texto el JSON filtrado anteriormente
    var cadena =JSON.stringify(Arr);
    
    //elimino las comillas de la cadena
    var comillas = '"';
    var vacio = '';
    var cadenaSinComillas = cadena.replaceAll(comillas, vacio);
}
```

cuando aplico console.log(cadenaSinComillas), dentro de la función, pruebo los desplegables y filtran de manera normal.

```
//las cadenas obtenidas tienen la siguinte forma
"[ new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447), new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.445), new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.443), ...]"
```

¿Cómo podría ingresarla en la plantilla de google heatmaps? pego la plantilla de la documentacion del sitio: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap?hl=es
Intenté retornar el valor de la función del evento con una funcion eval a la función disparador (eval(disparador()) pero no obtuve buenos resultados...

```
// This example requires the visualization. Include the libraries=visualization
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=visualization">

var map, heatmap;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: {lat: 37.775, lng: -122.434},
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });

    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: getPoints(),
        map: map
    });
 }

function toggleHeatmap() {
    heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
}

function changeGradient() {
    var gradient = [
        'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
        'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
        'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
        'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
        'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
    ]
    heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
}
function changeRadius() {
    heatmap.set('radius', heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20);
}
function changeOpacity() {
    heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2);
}

//Heatmap data:500 points
function getPoints() {
    return [
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447), //Supongo que aquí debería ingresar el resultado
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.445)  //de la función "disparador"
    ];
}
```

He intentado de varias maneras pero creo que estoy haciendo algo mal o tal vez debería verlo desde otra perspectiva, quise utilizar un return para llamar a la funcion desde la plantilla de heatmaps pero no dio resultados. disculpen la codificación no he sido instruido en programación aunque me llama bastante la atención. también mando el HTML (hay otros botones ahí con el evento onclick que modifican la apariencia del mapa):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <met  a charset="utf-8">
        <title>Heatmap</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/estilos.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="floating-panel">
            <button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Puntos</button>
            <button onclick="changeGradient()">Gradiente</button>
            <button onclick="changeRadius()">Radio</button>
            <button onclick="changeOpacity()">Opacidad</button>
        </div>
        
        <div id="floating-panel2">
            <select name="A" id="A" onchange="disparador()">
                <option select value="todos">Intervalo</option>
                <option select value="enero">Enero</option>
                <option select value="febrero">Febrero</option>
                <option select value="marzo">Marzo</option>
                <option select value="abril">Abril</option>
                <option select value="mayo">Mayo</option>
                <option select value="junio">Junio</option>
                <option select value="julio">Julio</option>
                <option select value="agosto">Agosto</option>
                <option select value="setiembre">Setiembre</option>
                <option select value="octubre">Octubre</option>
                <option select value="noviembre">Noviembre</option>
                <option select value="diciembre">Diciembre</option>
            </select>
            <select name="B" id="B" onchange="disparador()">
                <option select value="zonaA">Zona A</option>
                <option select value="zonaB">Zona B</option>
                <option select value="zonaC">Zona C</option>
                <option select value="zonaD">Zona D</option>
                <option select value="zonaE">Zona E</option>

            </select>   
            <select name="C" id="C" onchange="disparador()">
                <option select value="nombreA">Nombre A</option>
                <option select value="nombreB">Nombre B</option>
                <option select value="nombreC">Nombre C</option>
                <option select value="nombreD">Nombre D</option>
                <option select value="nombreE">Nombre E</option>
                <option select value="nombreF">Nombre F</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script src="JS/mapa.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/bd.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/filtrosbd.js"></script>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XxXxXxXxXxxXxXxXxxXxXXxXXxXXx&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces:

```
let coord = new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.443)
```

Eso es un objeto (de tipo google.maps.LatLng). Cuando lo pones como texto:

```
Arr[i] = " new google.maps.LatLng(" + filtrarC[i].Geolocalizacion + ")";
```

Sólo es eso. Un texto.

Si el resultado de tu filtro te da un arreglo tipo:

```
[ 
  "37.782, -122.447",
  "37.782, -122.445",
  "37.782, -122.443"
]
```

Entonces podrías usar

```
let Arr=[]
for(var i = 0; i<filtrarC.length;i++){
    let [lat, lng] =  filtrarC[i].Geolocalizacion.split(',')
    Arr[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
}
```

Ahora `Arr` es un array de posiciones.  Lo que haya en `Arr` está listo para pasarlo al heatmap. Olvídate de JSON.stringify

Dejo el ejemplo completo embelleciendo un poco la sintaxis del bucle

```js
let heatmap, map;

function getPoints() {
  let filtrarC = [
    "37.782, -122.447",
    "37.782, -122.445",
    "37.782, -122.443"
  ];

  return filtrarC.map(
    coord => new google.maps.LatLng(...coord.split(',').map(Number))
  )

}

function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 37.782,
      lng: -122.445
    },
    zoom: 14
  });
  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: getPoints(),
    map: map,
    radius: 20
  });
}
window.addEventListener('load', initMap)
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?library=visualization&key=AIzaSyBRqo4qwqHHrtbY9aL6vYYDw1GOhkK97MQ&libraries=visualization">
</script>
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:300px;"></div>
```